# Java 8 DateTime serialization and Jackson JSR 310

Tags: jackson, spring-boot, jsr310

I am using Java 8 DateTime and Jackson jsr 310 support in a Spring Boot application.

I disabled  **SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS** to force Jackson to serialize the localDatetime to string instead of int array.

But I found a weird format problem when the datetime microsecond or nonaseconds are end of 0. I think the serialized result could be equals the **date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)**, but it is not, the **format** method omitted the zeros.

The complete the example test codes.

```
private LocalDateTime date;

private OffsetDateTime offsetDate;

private ZonedDateTime zonedDate;

@Before
public void setup() throws ServletException {
    date = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 8, 15, 11, 40, 10, 100_000_000);
    offsetDate = OffsetDateTime.of(2015, 8, 15, 11, 40, 10, 100_000_000, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
    zonedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 8, 15, 11, 40, 10, 100_000_000, ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"));
}

@Test
public void testDateFormat() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("localDate", date);
    map.put("offsetDate", offsetDate);
    map.put("zonedDate", zonedDate);

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);

    log.debug("converted json result @" + json);

    JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);

    JsonNode localDateNode = rootNode.get("localDate");
    assertEquals("local date should be equals", date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME), localDateNode.textValue());

    JsonNode offsetDateNode = rootNode.get("offsetDate");
    assertEquals("offsetDate date should be equals", offsetDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), offsetDateNode.textValue());

    JsonNode zonedDateNode = rootNode.get("zonedDate");
    assertEquals("zonedDate date should be equals", zonedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME), zonedDateNode.textValue());

}
```

The test failed, and the log debug prints

```
{
    "zonedDate":"2015-08-15T11:40:10.100+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]",
    "localDate":"2015-08-15T11:40:10.100",
    "offsetDate":"2015-08-15T11:40:10.1+08:00"
}
```

**zonedDate** and **localDate** microseconds are end with **00**, but offsetDate is not. And **date.format** also get different result which micrseconds is **NOT** end with **00**.

The print result of format, toString, the json text

```
LocalDateTime format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)@2015-08-15T11:40:10.1
LocalDateTime toString                                     @2015-08-15T11:40:10.100
LocalDateTime serialized json node text                    @2015-08-15T11:40:10.100
OffsetDateTime format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)@2015-08-15T11:40:10.1+08:00
OffsetDateTime toString                                      @2015-08-15T11:40:10.100+08:00
OffsetDateTime serialized json node text                     @2015-08-15T11:40:10.1+08:00
ZonedDateTime format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)@2015-08-15T11:40:10.1+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]
ZonedDateTime toString                                     @2015-08-15T11:40:10.100+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]
ZonedDateTime serialized json node text                    @2015-08-15T11:40:10.100+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]
```

1. It seems the **toString** result should be the desired result in Jackson serialization, in above logging, **OffsetDateTime** json node microseconds text should be end with **00** .
2. Why the format method result omits the ending **00**?

The complete sample codes can be found from my github.com.

[angular-springmvc-sample-boot](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-springmvc-sample-boot)

[ISODateTest](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-springmvc-sample-boot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/hantsylabs/restexample/springmvc/test/ISODateTest.java)

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, I add my own serializer:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ").format(zonedDateTime));
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test has 2 problems:

1. You're comparing apples to oranges, `ObjectMapper` serialized result and `DateTimeFormatter` formatted result. Each has their own defaults and configuration options and it's no surprise that the results are different.
2. `100_000_000` is really `1`and according to [ISO_LOCAL_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME) definition, `DateTimeFormatter` prints "One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.". In your case, only 1 digit is required and that's exactly what you got in the output for `LocalDateTime`.

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do here and what is the purpose of the tests that you wrote. If you're expecting 3 digits of nanosecond precision from your formatter, you've to roll your own. Depending on `toString` formatting in your code is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What I confused is why the output format is not united in Jackson _ObjectMapper_.

Comment: If by "united" you mean if `ObjectMapper` internally uses `DateTimeFormatter`, it does. See [JavaTimeModule.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.java). However there are many configurations possible in Jackson that affect how datetime is parsed (or formatted). Look at `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature` for details.

Comment: It seems the latest 2.7.2 used `DateTimeFormatter` for LocalDateTime and OffsetDateTime serialization. But it does not use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` for `ZonedDateTime` serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for configuring the ObjectMapper.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```